# All-in-one tool to create and export all the iOS icon sizes

Tags: icon, export, ios

Hi I'm an iOS developer and I'm wondering how you design professionals create all those iOS icon sizes that are needed for an app.

For the most part I have seen this as a two-step process:

1. Create the icon image in one editor
2. Export it into the different sizes

Is there a tool that can easily do both? 
That isn't overly complicated? 
One button press and all your icons are created and appropriately named?

Comment: You want something that designs icons for you at the click of a button?

Comment: Depends what graphics program I am going to create the icon in.

Comment: @Cai, no not designs for me. Rather a tool I can use (like vector editor) and then click a button and it exports and renames the files to be iOS compliant with all the different sizes.

Comment: Hello @MarkMoeykens, welcome to GDSE! I think you might find the answer to your question here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42257/how-to-output-multiple-image-sizes-from-one-design/42287#42287

Comment: Thanks @PieBie. I think I'll be using Sketch for this problem. I'm trying to stay away from subscription based software since it is not my main profession. Sketch looks less-expensive in the long-run.

Comment: I built a [tool called Speculid](https://speculid.com/?utm_source=web&utm_medium=stackexchange&utm_campaign=launch-aug2018) which can **take SVG or PNG files and automatically export them to App Icons or Image Sets for use in Xcode**. It will read the metadata from the App Icon or Image Set and determine the formats and sizes needed and export the necessary files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my workflow, I would create icons as vectors by drawing them in either the [Sketch app](https://www.sketchapp.com/)(exclusive to Mac users) or Illustrator.

If in sketch, it has a range of export options that would do the trick. (there's a video on the page linked above that explains this a little more).

If in Illustrator, I would then save that file as a PSD in in Photoshop use [Generate](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html) to spit out the assets.

Either approach can export multiple assets in multiple sizes with a specified file name.

There is also [Adobe XD](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/experience-design.html) that is in Beta (currently exclusive to Mac users) but it would likely do the trick too.

Hope this has been helpful for you!

Comment: Thanks, Jenna. I looked at Sketch and while it doesn't have native support to automatically generate all the iOS icons for you it does have MANY plugins that will! Example: [Icon-Stamper](https://github.com/tylergaw/icon-stamper)